# How do I get the git commit description in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I need a safe consitent way to get the git description of latest commit in node.js

`git commit -m "some message" -m "this is the description"`

I am using `require('child_process').execSync('git log -1').toString();`

which outputs:

```
commit f8f42hash5556666b3c518e3hash294b62e88888
Author: Developer Name <email@email.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 28 08:10:09 2022 +0200

    some message

    this is the description
```

And I know that it is possible to add some `-format='????'` but following this guide; https://devhints.io/git-log-format I can't seem to find a option that gives me the description...

**Edit:** I see comments about description and message being treated as oine thing, which surprises me, because gitlabs interface can in fact tell the difference, I have also seen them as separetae fields in som GUI git manager (maybe git kraken or a vscode plugin)..

Here's how it looks in gitlab *(--skipSmokeTest is the description)*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the message like this:
`git log -1 --format='%b'`
It will return:

```
some message

this is the description
```

Then you can extract the second line of text using JavaScript.

Comment: Aha, so there is no way of getting just the description? I need it because I need to scan for certain keywords in the description, and it would be a problem if I also evaluate on the git message. I'm not sure I can extract the 2nd line of text, what if there is a linebreak in the git message, and no desription? Then I would accidentally evaluate on the message.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `git` doesn't differentiate between `message` and `description`. Just split by `\n\n` and get the second part.

Comment: @RasmusPuls There is no such thing as description, a commit only has a message, multiple -m will just concatenate multiple paragraphs into the message.

Comment: Some clients will differentiate the first line from the rest, will use the first line as the subject and the rest as body, this is why format has %s and %b.

Comment: Alright, I will use that logic then, evaluate on the parte after linebreak. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Beware the correct option is `--pretty` according to the [Git log doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/) !

For me, you should use this, it works for me: `git log -1 --pretty="format:%s"`.